# Unable to deploy firebase functions in functions emulator

Tags: node.js, firebase, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions

I am trying setup debugging (from IDE like VS Code) for Firebase Cloud Functions ,however unable to deploy them to the emulator. There is no official documentation about it but I am trying to follow [this article](https://medium.com/@mwebler/debugging-firebase-functions-with-vs-code-3afab528bb36).

```
functions deploy helloWorld --trigger-http --timeout 600s helloWorld
```

Error

```
Copying file:///tmp/tmp-24906PoEtMKaWT7sM.zip...
Waiting for operation to finish...done.
Deploying function......(node:24946) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error: read ECONNRESET
    at _errnoException (util.js:1022:11)
    at TCP.onread (net.js:628:25)
(node:24946) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). (rejection id: 1)
(node:24946) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.
```

I am aware of the [official guide](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/local-emulator) to deploying firebase function locally but there is no way I could set breakpoints and debug with that.

Is there any way to setup debugging?

Comment: The official documentation is here: [Run functions locally](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/local-emulator)